# How do you insert variable to url?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-delete

I search for a solution, and there are some answers but none solve my problem.
I want to add variable to the end of url which is user text input value (this is number of ID to delete in database).

```
var idRem = parseInt($('#removeId').val(),10);

            $removeBtn.on('click',function(){

                $.ajax({
                      type: 'DELETE',
                      url: "http://rest.learncode.academy/api/kuba/friends/"+idRem,
                      success: function() {
                        //no data...just a success (200) status code
                        console.log('Friend Deleted Successfully!');
                      },
                      error: function() {
                    alert('Deleting error');
                    }
                    });
                });
```

I see only error message, but when I put manually the value to the url or assign to variable then it works.

Is there anyone knows what is wrong?

Comment: What error message you are getting, you probably need to get the removeId value in click handler.

Comment: DELETE http://rest.learncode.academy/api/kuba/friends/NaN 400 (Bad Request), there is Nan instead of number even though I used parseInt

Comment: Have you checked value of `idRem` variable?

Comment: it seems that the problem is in this line: `var idRem = parseInt($('#removeId').val(),10);`

idRem is not getting a numerical value - hence - Not a Number (NaN)

Comment: When I type this in console var temp = parseInt($('#removeId').val(),10); I get number not string.typeof temp = "number"

Answer (score 0):

That's how I do it, and that's working..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btnAddToWatchlist').click(function(){

        location.href="<?php print Yii::app()->createUrl('Products/AddToWatchList'); ?>?id="+<?php print $productid ?>;

    });

});
```

Comment: Ok, but I prefer JS to PHP this time.

Comment: ok then..
just without yii::app()->createUrl..
you only need to add ?id="+<?php print $productid ?>

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are getting a NaN in your idRem variable then i think the problem is WHEN you are calling the initialization. 
I would try moving the `var idRem = parseInt($('#removeId').val(),10);` into the function call.
Problem might be that the parseInt is called on pageload when there is no value in the #removeId element.

Comment: When I declare 'idRem' with other variables and then idRem = parseInt($('#removeId').val(),10) in a function, there is  ReferenceError: idRem is not defined

Comment: try declaring + initializing it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource identified by the Request-URI.

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://rest.learncode.academy/api/kuba?" + $.param({"friends": idRem}),
type: 'DELETE',
success: function() {
//no data...just a success (200) status code
console.log('Friend Deleted Successfully!');
},
error: function() {
alert('Deleting error');
}
});
```